# clicking on a toggle bar unable to move banner image to down

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Clicking on a toggle bar unable to move the banner image down it is displaying the menu on the banner image.when the user clicks on toggle bar in mobile devices the menu should be displayed and below the menu, banner image should be displayed and if the user clicks on toggle bar again menu should be hidden and header should move up by default.Here is the code which I have used

```
<link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="slider">        
    <img src="images/backgroundbanner.jpg"  class="img-responsive backgroundbanner" alt="backgroundbanner" >
     <img src="images/finalbackgroundbanner.jpg"  class="img-responsive mobilebackgroundbanner" alt="backgroundbanner" >        
    <div class="banner_content home_new_section">
    <div class="b_head1"><span style="color:#26237B;font-weight:bold;">ONSHORE</span> <span style="color:#E2011B;font-weight:bold;">OFFSHORE</span> Team on Demand </div>

    <div class="b_head">Scale your Engineering&Technology team briskly</div>        
    <span class="pre_vetted">Pre-vetted, ready to go, $30 / hr</span>       
    </div>
    <div class="get_started"><a href="#" class="inline" id="link1">Get Started</a></div>

<!-- Navigation -->
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark fixed-top">
  <div class="container">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
      <img src="images/logo1.gif" width="110" height="26" alt="" class="logoimage img-responsive">

    </a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarCollapse" aria-controls="navbarResponsive" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>

    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarCollapse">
      <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto navbar-right">
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link home" href="#">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link cost" href="#" >Cost</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link offshore" href="http://teknotrait.com/">Offshore Partner</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link contactus" href="#contact" >Contact Us</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>

  </div>
</nav>
</div>   
<!-- Page Content -->
```

[Here](http://mkconsultantgroup.com) is the website url

Comment: What version of bootstrap are you using ?

Comment: @Zvezdas1989 i have downloaded one theme it is there by default in the theme